# Bedikas Chametz if staying at someones house (30 days prior to and) during Pesach

Tags: passover, chametz-leaven, bedikas-chametz

I was looking on halachapedia and different sources, but I couldn't find an answer to a particular question:

If a Jew is staying at someone else's house (whether a Jew or a gentile, but let's say it's a Jew who doesn't necessarily keep the laws of Passover), then what's the deal with Bedikas Chametz?

If that person has a private bedroom within the house, is Bedikah required just there? What if they share a living room and kitchen, if the other person is Jewish do they both have to do Bedikah and make sure that there's no chametz in the house? Is the fact that its an apartment in a complex that is owned by gentiles significant?

In order words:

**Whats required in Bedikas Chametz if someone is staying at another's house (let's say he's Jewish but doesn't necessarily keep the laws of Pesach) ?**

Comment: Halachipedia “and different sources”? Where have you checked already, so that others don’t waste time looking at things you’ve already confirmed don’t discuss this?

Answer (score 1):

A Q & A [article on OUKosher.org](https://oukosher.org/passover/articles/bedikat-chametz/) by R' Eli Eleff seems to address your question. Namely:

> IF I AM A GUEST AT SOMEONE’S HOUSE, DO I NEED TO DO BEDIKAT CHAMETZ?

No. If one is a guest they may rely on the owner. However, if the host is around, one should ask them if the home was checked.

> MY NEIGHBOR IS SELLING HIS HOUSE AND GOING AWAY FOR PASSOVER, CAN I HOUSE MY GUESTS THERE IF NO ONE DID A BEDIKA? AND, IF NOT, FOR WHICH ROOMS MUST A BEDIKA BE DONE?

You must perform a bedika on all rooms that will be used over Passover.

> IF I RENT OUT MY HOUSE, DO I NEED TO DO A BEDIKA BEFORE I LEAVE? WHAT ABOUT THE PERSON RENTING FROM ME?

If you rent out your house to another Jew and you gave him the keys before the eve of the 14th, it is the renter’s obligation to check for chametz on the premises.

---

**Bottom Line**: We could deduce from the above that in the scenario you propose one **should** do a bedikah.

(for further reference see: "[Hilchot Pesach: Bedikat Chametz](https://www.ou.org/holidays/passover/hilchos_pesach/)" another ou.org article)